# REACT NATIVE IOS SIMULATOR SHOWING BLANK BLACK SCREEN WHILE LAUNCHING BEFORE EVEN RUNNING SPLASH SCREEN

Tags: android, reactjs, xcode, react-native-ios

I have a react native application that is working well without any issues. But I changed the device orientation to all four options in xcode. After that while launching the application react native ios app is just showing up with a black screen before even launching the splash screen. Can i know what is the issue. I have tried numerous things from stackoverflow but nothing worked till now.

my AppDelegae.m file...

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

#if DEBUG
#import <FlipperKit/FlipperClient.h>
#import <FlipperKitLayoutPlugin/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin/FKUserDefaultsPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitNetworkPlugin/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin.h>
#import <SKIOSNetworkPlugin/SKIOSNetworkAdapter.h>
#import <FlipperKitReactPlugin/FlipperKitReactPlugin.h>

static void InitializeFlipper(UIApplication *application) {
  FlipperClient *client = [FlipperClient sharedClient];
  SKDescriptorMapper *layoutDescriptorMapper = [[SKDescriptorMapper alloc] initWithDefaults];
  [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitLayoutPlugin alloc] initWithRootNode:application withDescriptorMapper:layoutDescriptorMapper]];
  [client addPlugin:[[FKUserDefaultsPlugin alloc] initWithSuiteName:nil]];
  [client addPlugin:[FlipperKitReactPlugin new]];
  [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitNetworkPlugin alloc] initWithNetworkAdapter:[SKIOSNetworkAdapter new]]];
  [client start];
}
#endif

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
#if DEBUG
  InitializeFlipper(application);
#endif

  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                   moduleName:@"PipeApp"
                                            initialProperties:nil];

  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

@end
```

and this is my pod file ...

```
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'


platform :ios, '14.2'


target 'PipeApp' do
  config = use_native_modules!
  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])

  pod 'RNFS', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fs'

  pod 'react-native-cameraroll', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cameraroll'

  pod 'react-native-torch', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-torch'

  pod 'RNSVG', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-svg'

  target 'PipeAppTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  use_flipper!
  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
  end
end

target 'PipeApp-tvOS' do
  # Pods for RNTodo-tvOS

  target 'PipeApp-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end
```

Hopefully someone might help me with this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Check the behaviour on physical device with release build.

Comment: It is doing the same on the physical device too...